# set datetime value in input html from php

Tags: php, html, datetime, input

I just try to set a value datetime for input( It is for change the current value of variable date time), but my html show an error ( seems it's fault about the format):

the code is :

`<input type="datetime" name="deadline" required value ='<?php echo date('c', $dateDeadline); ?>'/>`

Thx a lot.

Comment: in your current code, `$dateDeadline` is undefined, and may not be in unix time

Comment: The value of $dateDeadline is '2014-06-21 12:32:0'

Comment: if it is defined, your should wrap it with `<?php echo date('c', strtotime($dateDeadline));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$dateDeadiline` is indeed defined, your should wrap it with `strtotime()`.

On the [**`manual`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date.php):

> **`string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`**

You should provide a `timestamp`, not a string date. Consider this example:

```
<?php
$dateDeadiline = '2014-06-21 12:32:00';
?>
<input type="datetime" name="deadline" required value="<?php echo date('c', strtotime($dateDeadiline)); ?>" />
```

Using `DateTime` Class with timezone:

```
<?php $date = new DateTime('2014-06-21 12:32:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); ?>
<input type="datetime" name="deadline" required value="<?php echo $date->format('c'); ?>" />
```

For list of supported timezones, you can check this link:

> http://www.php.net//manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: And if i want to set a datetime-zone ? I try to convert into the same format but the input don't show it. If I show in another site the date format is the same than the input requieres:

21/06/2014 12:32 and the input requieres dd/mm/aa --:--

Comment: @user3157778 if you want to set the timezone you might want to look at the `DateTime` class, as it is more flexible than this current solution. check my edit

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes for your value attribute that are conflicting with your PHP code. Try this instead:

```
<input type="datetime" name="deadline" required value="<?php echo date('c', $dateDeadline); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set by a given variable as well

```
<?php echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($given_time)) ?>
```